# import data and indexes in microsoft sql server

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I am transfering data from one server to another using microsoft sql server management studio. Every time I import data from another server, it doesnt come with the indexes and constraints, it just transfers the data without importing the indexes for the table, How do I import both the data and the indexes?

Comment: How are you exporting the table from the source server?. Are you exporting the whole database or table by table?.

Answer (score 0):

First set the **Script Indexes** to true in below location.

```
SSMS-->Tools-->Options-->SQL Server Object Explorer-->Scripting-->Script Indexes.
```

Try generating the script again by, right clicking on the table and choose "Script Table as" to generate the script

You can also export by right clicking on the database-->Tasks and choose generate scripts.

Let me know if you still face any issues.